# How do I determine feats for a new character?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, feats

I always get hung up on feats when creating a new character in D&D 3.5. Specifically, this part of the fighter description from the SRD has me really stumped:

> At 1st level, a fighter gets a bonus combat-oriented feat in addition
>   to the feat that any 1st-level character gets and the bonus feat
>   granted to a human character...
>
> These bonus feats are in addition to the feat that a character of any
>   class gets from advancing levels. A fighter is not limited to the list
>   of fighter bonus feats when choosing these feats. ([source](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/fighter.htm))

If I understand this correctly:

- All 1st-level characters get to choose a feat - and it can be any feat - while a 1st-level fighter gets to choose two
- All 1st-level human characters get to choose a two feats, and 1st-level human fighters get to choose three

Is this right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is 100% correct. A character gains a feat at first level, and every 3rd level (3, 6, 9 etc.) A Human gains an additional feat at first level. These feats can be anything you qualify for by meeting the prerequisites. Some classes, like the fighter, grant bonus feats which are on top of any other feats and often have restrictions on what feats they can be.

Comment: These are separate from special abilities gained per level according to class, right? So at level three a druid character gains the trackless step ability and any feat of their choosing?

Comment: Yes. There is a chart in the players handbook on page 22, table 3-2 which summarizes the benefits you get from leveling. All characters gain these benefits, which include feats at 1st level and every 3rd level. Beyond that you have class features, things like a rouge's sneak attack, a druid's wild shape, fighter bonus feats, etc. You gain those at the level it says in the class table.

Comment: @Koveras Those are _completely different_ from feats, and _completely unrelated_ to them. ("Feat" is not sure for "feature" or "class feature", it's [just feat](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/feat))

Comment: I probably should but don't have the player's handbook. Can this stuff be found in the SRD?

Comment: The specific table, no. It involves specifics about D&D, not just the D20 system, so it is not OGL (Open Gaming Liscense). This is stated in the FAQ http://www.d20srd.org/faq.htm

Comment: You should get the players handbook. It contains a character creation guide, and other sources like d20srd are not legally allowed to publish it.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea the SRD was missing so much. Thanks for the link. Now I'm confused how I've managed to play with my friends for years without anyone owning a single book...

Comment: @Koveras Specifically, the SRD is not (and was never designed to be) a complete game, just a reference for designers who want to make compatible materials, so it's not written as a teaching document. Lots of people learn to play using the just the SRD, but a lot of how the full game is supposed to work gets lost that way.